# Parse search/replace header file with formatted results

Tags: c++, c, shell, awk

I have a header file with lots of `#define` macros in the form of `AAA_xxxxx`, where `AAA` is always set of tri-codes and `xxxxx` is always a numerical value. I need to modify the file so the `#define AAA_xxxxx` is put back into the file as `#define AAA_xxxxx xxxxx`.

The best example I can come up with are Oracle ORA-xxx (error codes). For example if I have a line like ...

```
#define ORA_00001    // "unique constraint violated"
```

I need a script that will replace the line so that it looks like ...

```
#define ORA_00001  00001  // "unique constraint violated"
```

... without modifying the rest of the file or line itself.

I believe `awk` is my answer but I can't seem to get the syntax down correctly ...

```
awk '{ if ( $1 == "#define" ) parse_and_print_the_line($0)  ; else print $0 }'
```

Any ideas (awk or not) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: congrats, 70.000th question in C on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple Perl script:

```
perl -i -pe 's{^(#define(\s+)[A-Z]{3}_(\d+))(?=\s*\/\/|\s*$)}{$1$2$3}' file_to_modify.h
```

It finds any line that matches either of these patterns:

```
#define  XYZ_1234234456
#define  XYZ_1234234456    // comment
```

and changes it to the corresponding one of these patterns:

```
#define  XYZ_1234234456  1234234456
#define  XYZ_1234234456  1234234456    // comment
```